# Number of Tuesdays in five consecutive calendar years taken together is exactly 260. Which day of the week was 1st Jan. of the first of five years?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, calendar-computations

Number of Tuesdays in five consecutive calendar years taken together is exactly 260. Which day of the week was 1st January of the first of these five years?

I don't know at all how to do this question. I know that in leap year there are 2 odd days and in ordinary year there is 1 odd day.

Comment: how many days in 5 years ( there are only two possibilities total)

Comment: 1 leap year and 4 ordinary year. Means 6 odd days @RoddyMacPhee and two leap years and 3 ordinary years. Am I right?

Comment: I was more talking total than "odd days"  the two configurations are 5 normal years ( example 996-1000 AD ( except it was julian calendar back then))  or four normal years and a leap year  take the remainder mod 7 and that will be the difference in days of the week from start to finish  the division itself is how many weeks there are.  that will help determine if tuesday needs to show up in the last partial week.

Comment: Okay, what you said was a bit tough to understand @RoddyMacPhee

Comment: 365*4+366 = 1460+366=1826  has a remainder of 6 when divided by 7 and divides by 7 to give 260 so Tuesday can't be one of the 6 days can it ?

Comment: I understood till 1826 will give remainder 6. @RoddyMacPhee

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63714/discussion-between-roddy-macphee-and-sakuzi-markel).

Answer (score 0):

One year is 365 days = 52 weeks plus one day, or 366 days = 52 weeks plus 2 days. 5 consecutive years contain 0, 1 or 2 leap years. But 2 leap years means 260 weeks plus 7 extra days, therefore 261 weeks and 261 Tuesdays. 1 leap year means 260 weeks plus 6 extra days, or 6 days plus 260 weeks. The first 6 days must not contain a Tuesday so they must be Wednesday to Monday. First day of the first year is Wednesday.

What about no leap years: The same reasoning shows the first day of the first year is Wednesday or Thursday. 1900, 1800, 1700 were not leap years, neither will 2100, 2200 or 2300 be. The five years might start for example in 1896, 1897, 1898 or 1899 (not 1900 to 1904).

January 1st 2099 was a Thursday, and none of the years 2099 to 2103 is a leap year. This doesn’t happen for the years around 1700, 1800 or 1900.

Result: The first day of the first year can be Wednesday or Thursday.

Answer (score 0):

Since $5*52=260$, the question is equivalent to asking what day of the week the first year must begin on if none of five consecutive years has 53 Tuesdays.

A year will have 53 Tuesdays if the dominical letter is F, FE, or GF.

Examining the possibilities for the dominical letters (including the cases involving non-leap century years) gives the following:

- AG, F, E, D, CB (second year has 53 Tuesdays)
- GF, E, D, C, BA (first year has 53 Tuesdays)
- FE, D, C, B, AG (first year has 53 Tuesdays)
- ED, C, B, A, GF (fifth year has 53 Tuesdays)
- DC, B, A, G, FE (fifth year has 53 Tuesdays)
- CB, A, G, F, ED (fourth year has 53 Tuesdays)
- BA, G, F, E, DC (third year has 53 Tuesdays)
- A, GF, E, D, C (second year has 53 Tuesdays)
- G, FE, D, C, B (second year has 53 Tuesdays)
- F, ED, C, B, A (first year has 53 Tuesdays)
- E, DC, B, A, G
- D, CB, A, G, F (fifth year has 53 Tuesdays)
- C, BA, G, F, E (fourth year has 53 Tuesdays)
- B, AG, F, E, D (third year has 53 Tuesdays)
- A, G, FE, D, C (third year has 53 Tuesdays)
- G, F, ED, C, B (second year has 53 Tuesdays)
- F, E, DC, B, A (first year has 53 Tuesdays)
- E, D, CB, A, G
- D, C, BA, G, F (fifth year has 53 Tuesdays)
- C, B, AG, F, E (fourth year has 53 Tuesdays)
- B, A, GF, E, D (third year has 53 Tuesdays)
- A, G, F, ED, C (third year has 53 Tuesdays)
- G, F, E, DC, B (second year has 53 Tuesdays)
- F, E, D, CB, A (first year has 53 Tuesdays)
- E, D, C, BA, G
- D, C, B, AG, F (fifth year has 53 Tuesdays)
- C, B, A, GF, E (fourth year has 53 Tuesdays)
- B, A, G, FE, D (fourth year has 53 Tuesdays)
- $2096, 2097, 2098, 2099, 2100$ ($2097$ has 53 Tuesdays)
- $2097, 2098, 2099, 2100, 2101$ ($2097$ has 53 Tuesdays)
- $2098, 2099, 2100, 2101, 2102$
- $2099, 2100, 2101, 2102, 2103$
- $2100, 2101, 2102, 2103, 2104$ ($2104$ has 53 Tuesdays)
- $2196, 2197, 2198, 2199, 2200$ ($2199$ has 53 Tuesdays)
- $2197, 2198, 2199, 2200, 2201$ ($2199$ has 53 Tuesdays)
- $2198, 2199, 2200, 2201, 2202$ ($2199$ has 53 Tuesdays)
- $2199, 2200, 2201, 2202, 2203$ ($2199$ has 53 Tuesdays)
- $2200, 2201, 2202, 2203, 2204$
- $2296, 2297, 2298, 2299, 2300$
- $2297, 2298, 2299, 2300, 2301$ ($2301$ has 53 Tuesdays)
- $2298, 2299, 2300, 2301, 2302$ ($2301$ has 53 Tuesdays)
- $2299, 2300, 2301, 2302, 2303$ ($2301$ has 53 Tuesdays)
- $2300, 2301, 2302, 2303, 2304$ ($2301$ has 53 Tuesdays)

For the cases that do not involve non-leap century years, one can see that the first year must be a non-leap year beginning on a Wednesday.

For the cases that involve non-leap century years, the above $15$ cases are the only ones that one need to check for because the Gregorian calendar repeats every $400$ years. Of those $15$ cases, $4$ of them do not contain a year with $53$ Tuesdays. The years $2098, 2200,$ and $2296$ begin on Wednesdays, while the year $2099$ begins on a Thursday.

So, the answer is that the first year must usually begin on a Wednesday. Once every $400$ years, there is a solution beginning with a year that begins on a Thursday (namely, the years $2099$ to $2103$).